# How do I prevent Bitcoin from synchronizing?

Tags: bitcoind, synchronization

I have a script that uses Bitcoin's RPC interface and takes a lot of CPU to run, and I don't want Bitcoin to be verifying blocks while I do it. Is there a config setting or an RPC call I can use to stop it from syncing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
bitcoin-cli invalidateblock `bitcoin-cli getbestblockhash`
```

or

```
bitcoind -maxconnections=0
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Can you tell me, how can I "undo" the `invalidateblock` command so the sync will be continued?

Comment: `reconsiderblock <hash>`

Comment: Is invalidateblock still working? How much of a hack is this? Is there a less hacky way to do this already? Like a config entry?

Comment: It still works.